# logitech mouse shorts over rdp

Tags: remote-desktop, mouse, paste, copy

I have a logitech g602 and i have created shortcuts on the mouse G-buttons for copy and paste. 
I want to see if its possible for me to use the same shortcuts when im working on an RDP machine. I do a lot of copy pasting from local machine to rdp machine and would be great if somehow i can also maybe install logitech drivers on the rdp machine then be able to use the mouse shortcuts? 
example. right now my G6 button is ctrl+v (paste) but when i click that button in the rdp machine in notepad it types v , but if i hold down the ctrl button on the pc then click that button it does paste. point is to find out if its possible to pass these commands from the mouse over rdp session to remote desktop. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and none of the solutions I found through google worked.

What worked for me was to user the "Multikey Macro" option instead of simple keystrokes.

Make sure you check the "record delays between events option"

And then after you've recorded your macro you can adjust the delays between key events to something shorter.

[image: Multi key macro example]

Putting 50ms delays between each action makes the macro work flawlessly for me over RDP.

Comment: Fix the issue using my G700s!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the solution that (mostly) worked is to go to the Logitech Gaming Software and on the home screen toggle from "Onboard Memory" to "Automatic Game Detection". This apparently stores the profile on the computer instead of the mouse and allows the modifier keys to work more appropriately.

I still have some trouble with a few things (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> works, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> omits the shift key in Remote desktop), but most funtions are working.  I have copy and paste assigned to two of the buttons and they now work instead of just putting 'v' or 'c'.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue.  I put 200ms delays in between the pressing of the modifyer keys and the selection of the letter key  ex:

press ctrl
pause 200
press c
release c
release ctrl

i found 500 was a bit much.   also, when switching to other programs, ex: Win + 1 through win + 9, i had issues when i attempted to leave the combination pressed for a few seconds.  when i did that, it would flicker/strobe the programs (word, outlook, excel).   I wish we could type content via a macro.  or if there was a way to store multiple clipboards in an app with rdp.  i got this mouse with the hopes of creating an excel database with quick access/ recall to the data on the fly